# Двумерные массивы в динамической памяти

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

**Задача:** создать двумерный массив в динамической памяти, количество строк, колонок и сами элементы которого вводит пользователь. Далее нужно суммировать элементы строк и поместить эти суммы в новый массив.
**Что не понятно:** не могу логически дойти до того, в каком порядке расположить циклы в цикле, чтобы сумма отдельной строки записывалась в отдельный элемент нового массива res. Данный пример кода суммирует все элементы двумерного массива и записывает одинаковое значение во все элементы массива res.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void mass()
{
int r, c;
cout << "Enter rows and columns:" << endl;
cin >> r >> c;
int** arr = new int* [r];
for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
{
    arr[i] = new int[c];
}

cout << "Enter values of array:" << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < c; j++)
    {
        cin >> arr[i][j];
    }
    cout << endl;
}

for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < c; j++)
    {
        cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int* res = new int[r] {};


for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < r; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < r; k++)
        {
            res[k] += arr[i][j];
        }
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
{
    cout << res[i] << " ";
}

for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
{
    delete[] arr[i];
}

delete[] arr;

delete[] res;
```

}

**Вывод:**

2 5 7 3

3 6 7 4

2 5 6 8

3 2 5 3

71 71 71 71

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Суммируйте прямо при вводе:

```
cout << "Enter values of array:" << endl;

int* res = new int[r] {};

for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
{
    res[i] =  0;
    for (int j = 0; j < c; j++)
    {
        cin >> arr[i][j];
        res[i] += arr[i][j];
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```